# Encrypting RHEL8's /boot & /boot/efi on a UEFI machine

Tags: rhel, uefi, luks

My objective is to encrypt my /boot and /boot/efi partitions with luks1 on a RHEL8 UEFI secure boot system for full system encryption.

I am able to encrypt (LUKS1) my /boot partition in a BIOS mode RHEL8 install and update grub to preload the necessary crypto modules, but I am trying to encrypt my /boot AND /boot/efi partitions on a UEFI machine.  I can get everything encrypted, but I am having a problem updating GRUB2 to accept the new parameters.  My basic steps are:

- Copy the /boot and /boot/efi partition data to /root
- Unmount both partitions
- Convert partitions to luks1, encrypt, remount, and move data back
- Fix fstab and crypttab with new UUIDs
- Create new grub config using grub2-mkconfig (this modifies the /boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg file appropriately with insmod cryptodisk and other entries)
- Install new bootloader

Everything works except modifying the bootloader (GRUB2).  Using grub2-install, I receive an error that grub2 cannot update a uefi secure boot system.  Tried using efibootmgr, but seems like this program doesn't reinstall the bootloader, only manages current entries.

Is there a program I can use to reinstall the grub bootloader on a UEFI secure boot system that has the necessary luks1 crypto support?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: UEFI firmware needs a fat32 filesystem to boot EFI executables from. The spec doesn’t include the firmware (BIOS) unlocking a LUKS volume. You will need an unencrypted volume to launch the EFI executable (grub2). You can add a password to your grub.conf.

Comment: The EFI partition is read by BIOS to boot. Obviously you cannot encrypt it unless the BIOS can decrypt it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies...
Generically, UEFI system, GRUB bootloader is installed on /dev/sda, /boot/efi on /dev/sda1, and /boot on /dev/sda2.  On BIOS, GRUB is on /dev/sda, and /boot on /dev/sda1.  
GRUB2 has support for encrypted volumes; I have been able to encrypt /boot on a BIOS system forcing GRUB to unlock the luks1 /boot volume and then the kernel to unlock the /(root) luks2 encrypted volume; password twice at boot.

I've also encrypted /boot on EFI system & made that work; again, password twice at boot.  But still need to encrypt the /boot/efi partition for full disk encryption.